# Valgrind...Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s),

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, valgrind

I was trying to design a simple c program of array with the help of few pointers. In the following program, the length of an array was taken from user and passed to a function int *array(int length). Within this function the user was asked to enter integer numbers in array. The function returns a pointer(*s) which points towards the very first element of the array. That pointer is received in main and the values of array are printed with the help of that pointer as the program follows.

```
//creating array in a different function with pointer help//
#include<stdio.h>

int *array(int length);

int main(void)
{
 int i, length, *p = NULL;

 printf("enter array length:");
 scanf("%i", &length);

 //passing array length to function and receiving the pointer to first element of array//
 p = array(length);

 //printing array elements with pointer help//
 printf("created array:");

 for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
 {
     printf("%i ", *(p+i));
 }

 printf("\n");

}

//function to enter values in array//

int *array(int length)

{
 
 int i, *s = NULL, series[length];

 //asking user to put values in array//
 for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
 {
     printf("entry %i:", i+1);
     scanf("%i", &series[i]);
 }

 //pointer pointing to first element of array//
 s = &series[0];
 return s;
 }
```

The program works fine but valgrind was giving error as "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" and also Use of uninitialised value of size 8. For eg, I am getting folowing output for entering 3 integer values in array.

::Normal Output::

enter array length:3

entry 1:23

entry 2:19

entry 3:34

created array:23 19 34

:::Output with Valgrind:::

enter array length:3

entry 1:23

entry 2:19

entry 3:34

created array:==9585== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

==9585==    at 0x4A5B958: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)

==9585==    by 0x4A5DEA1: buffered_vfprintf (vfprintf-internal.c:2377)

==9585==    by 0x4A5AD23: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1346)

==9585==    by 0x4A45D3E: printf (printf.c:33)

==9585==    by 0x4011CE: main (rd.c:21)

==9585==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation

==9585==    at 0x4011A0: main (rd.c:19)

==9585==

==9585== Use of uninitialised value of size 8

==9585==    at 0x4A3F69B: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)

==9585==    by 0x4A5B574: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1687)

==9585==    by 0x4A5DEA1: buffered_vfprintf (vfprintf-internal.c:2377)

==9585==    by 0x4A5AD23: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1346)

==9585==    by 0x4A45D3E: printf (printf.c:33)

==9585==    by 0x4011CE: main (rd.c:21)

==9585==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation

==9585==    at 0x4011A0: main (rd.c:19)

---

This errors I am getting repeatedly 5 times in output. I figured out that the problem is happening somehow while receiving the return value(which is apparently a pointer) in main function but unable to get clear understanding of it.
This same program I did by dynamic memory allocation(using malloc) and it works fine without any error. But I wonder how this one is giving error. Can anyone provide clear explanation about the reason of 'conditional jump' error appearing on output and perhaps any solution for it?

Comment: Is your compiler not screaming bloody murder about returning the address of the local array `series`? If not, turn up your warnings until it does.

Comment: The mistake is not about the conditional jump - it's actually about the fact you are using a pointer to a destroyed local variable

Comment: In your `array` function you want: `int *series = malloc(sizeof(*series) * length);` Now `series` is a pointer to heap allocated memory that _persists_ when the function returns instead of a local array on the stack that goes out of scope when the function returns